# Border not showing up and stack panel disappears

Tags: wpf, xaml

Whenever I try to add a panel to the following grid the border does not show up and the stack panel with the text disappears and I do not understand why
This is how the code looks before me trying to add a border to the whole grid.

```
  <Grid Name="grdContext" Grid.Column="2" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Margin="0" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="6*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock Name="lblDate" Foreground="White" Background="Black" FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Margin="5,5,5,2.5">07/01/2016</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Name="lblTime"  Foreground="White" Background="Black" FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Margin="5,2.5,5,5">14:27</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
        <Image Name="imgArchive" Grid.Row="2" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Stretch="UniformToFill" Margin="0,0.4,10,10"/>
    </Grid>
```

and this is after

```
<Border BorderBrush="DimGray" BorderThickness="3">
      <Grid Name="grdContext" Grid.Column="2" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Margin="0" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="6*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock Name="lblDate" Foreground="White" Background="Black" FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Margin="5,5,5,2.5">07/01/2016</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Name="lblTime"  Foreground="White" Background="Black" FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Margin="5,2.5,5,5">14:27</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
        <Image Name="imgArchive" Grid.Row="2" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Stretch="UniformToFill" Margin="0,0.4,10,10"/>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Nothing is visible when I out in the border, what is going on?

Comment: Move `Grid.Column="2"` from the `Grid` to the `Border` ?

Comment: Could you tell me why you suggested that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Slyvain noticed, you broke the visual tree.

In your first code sample you have

```
MainGrid
column 0 asign foo
column 1 asign fooo
column 2 asign grdContext
```

Second sample

```
MainGrid
column 0 asign foo
column 1 asign fooo
Border?
```